# Android - UI issue

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]Hi,

I need to design an UI similar to my attached image. I need help on setting the TextView such as it is center aligned with radiobuttons. The center position of TextView and center position of radiobutton should be in same vertical line.

Comment: Use relative Layout and do some googling before asking question,,,

Comment: Can you please post any sample ?

Comment: agree with L7ColWinters and Samir.

Comment: @Samir, i KNOW TO GOOGLE. AND I KNOW RELATIVE LAYOUT TOO. But i missed adding both aligning left and right "android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioButton2" so that it gets set in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlCell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton android:text="" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/radioButton1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
    <TextView android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioButton1"></TextView>

    <RadioButton android:text="" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radioButton1"  android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
    <TextView android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioButton2"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it wont work. Because aligning left and right will not render the required UI. If the Textview length is longer than the radiobutton, then the radio button should be positioned in the middle of the textview. BUt in this code, if textview length is long, the Text moves to next line.

Comment: If i do it this way, the view will not look consistent across different screen sizes.